# Sum of squares in one Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say we want this in a Excel cell:

```
= (B10-A1)^2
 +(C10-A1)^2
 +(D10-A1)^2
 +...
 +(FG10-A1)^2
```

Is there a way to make such a sum in one cell, without using other intermediary cells for the calculation, and without VBA, just with built-in Excel functions?

Comment: Don't have time to play now, but indirect() with sumproduct() ?

Comment: What is your expected visual result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's what [SUMSQ()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumsq-function-e3313c02-51cc-4963-aae6-31442d9ec307) is meant to do I suppose:

```
=SUMSQ(B10:FG10-A1)
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> if working on an older Excel version prior to dynamic array functionality.

Comment: If I just do ENTER, it gives a wrong result, if I do CTRL SHIFT ENTER it becomes `{=SOMME.CARRES(A1:A4-1)}`, and it seems correct. Why the `{` `}`?   Note: `SOMME.CARRES` is `SUMSQ` in French

Comment: Because as mentioned, you probably don't have a newer version of Excel yet that does the CSE for you =). Note the curly brackets indicate an array to be summed.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV! I'm trying to understand why a new feature (I currently don't know the dynamic array feature) is needed to compute `=SUMSQ(B10:FG10-A1)`. What makes this formula special so that it requires a new feature (said differently : what is special in this formula that makes it different on new Excel vs. old Excel)? It looks like a normal formula, so I don't see why it produces different results if E or CSE.

Comment: Right, so the idea is that older versions of Excel work on the principle that a single cell can show a single value, therefor a mechanism called implicit intersection prevents the given range of cells to be computed in your formula, but instead only the top-left value in the array/range is calculated (note the "wrong" result, it's just the result of the top-left cell). Ever since ms365 this behaviour called implicit intersection is levitated and replaced with dynamic array funcitonality. Meaning; the standard is no longer a single value compute but a whole array.

Comment: You can read more on the principle [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUM(MAP(B10:D10,LAMBDA(z,(z-1)^2)))
```

Or just:

```
=SUM((B10:D10-A1)^2)
```

Result:

[image]

Update range according to your dataset.